# How to redirect VM DNS question to host machine localhost dnsmasq

Tags: iptables, virtual-machine, nat, tap

My local network shcema is something like this:

```
internet (WAN)
  |
router            host IP (resolv.conf)
  |                |
  +------- eth0 - br0 - tap0 - VM (resolv.conf)
  |                |
localnet          localhost (dnsmasq)
 (.home)
```

My host computer is used mainly for testing virtual machines.
The goal is to let the VM to see the local net only, not to get DNS from the WAN, but get it from `dnsmasq`, which is configured to listen on host `lo` interface and to know just hosts from the localnet: `pc1.home` `pc2.home` `www.home` `data.home` `printer.home` ...

I succefully configured the dnsmasq to listen on `tcp/udp 127.0.0.1:53` on the host machine, and check it by getting answer form host cli:

```
# dig www.google.com    ... 142.251.36.68 (ANSWER 1)
```

and

```
# dig @127.0.0.1 www.google.com    ...    (ANSWER 0)
# dig @127.0.0.1 www.home ... 192.168.1.2 (ANSWER 1)
```

I set the ip_forwarding in various ways

```
# echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ip4/conf/all/forwarding
# echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tap0/route_localnet
```

Then I tried to compose the iptables rule:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tap0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:53
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tap0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:53
```

followed by check

```
# iptables -v -t nat -L
 pkts bytes target  prot opt in    out  source    destination         
    0     0 DNAT    udp  --  tap0  any  anywhere  anywhere    udp dpt:domain   to:127.0.0.1:53
    0     0 DNAT    tcp  --  tap0  any  anywhere  anywhere    tcp dpt:domain   to:127.0.0.1:53
```

But while running my virtual linux, the DNS is still answered from router nameserver listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Well, you can advice me to rewrite the `resolv.conf` of virtual machine manulaly, but as I test the installation of many VM it is annoying to do that each time, and it is hardly to say, what to write there, because the dnsmasq listens at localhost of the host machine. Hence the content of VM `resolv.conf` like

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

could be very confusing and useless.
I tried to capture some packets with Wireshark, but it just showed me that no redirection takes place, but not why.

Comment: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340975/common-dns-for-virtual-machines-with-iptables-netfilter) looks like what you want to do

Comment: Thanks for the link, I need to tune up this configuration over this weekend